# Do I have to manually delete branches in Xcode 8 after they have been properly merged into main, and deleted through Github?

Tags: xcode, git, github

I am currently using github to manage a swift 3 project that I am working on in Xcode 8. I created a branch titled "myBranch" in the terminal, and after merging, fixing my conflicts, and then merging again, I was able to "delete" "myBranch" through the github pull requests manager. I ran my app and it worked as expected. However, when I go to Source Control --> "myRepo" --> configure "myRepo", "myBranch" still appears. I also typed in "git branch" in the terminal, and "myBranch" once again appeared. On the github site, it says I only have one branch, master.

Since the deletion of the branch through github did not affect Xcode or the terminal automatically, should I go into Xcode and the terminal and delete the branch manually? I am a bit new to GitHub so I do not want to delete anything and potentially disrupt my project.

Answer (score 0):

If myBranch is no more required in local.
Yes, it must be deleted in local manually(though it is already deleted in remote (github site)). Since git tracks local and remote branches separately.

You can view a list of all the local branches on your machine by running git branch:

```
$ git branch
  master
* myBranch
```

Each local branch has a file under .git/refs/heads/:

```
$ tree -F .git/refs/heads/

    .git/refs/heads/
    ├── master
    └── myBranch
```

Each remote-tracking branch has a file under .git/refs/remote/:

```
$ tree -F .git/refs/remotes/

  .git/refs/remotes/
  ├── remote/
    ├── master
    └── myBranch
```

- To delete a local branch, whether tracking or non-tracking, safely:

> git branch -d myBranch

- To delete a local branch, whether tracking or non-tracking,
  forcefully:

> git branch -D myBranch

- To delete a remote-tracking branch:

> git branch -rd remote/myBranch